# Angular: How to delete selected data row?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, radio-button

I'm using `<mat-radio-button>` list. When I click first and then I click second than I click first back. When I click the first radio button back it not function. And then when I click delete button, it deletes first and second.

I provided the code below and a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-kttsot) link for your reference.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-chip class="pointer" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="removeSelectedRows()">
    Remove Selected Rows
  </mat-chip>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <!-- <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox> -->
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-radio-button (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
             (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="3"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 >
  </mat-paginator>

</div>
```

**Component**

```
    displayedColumns = ['select', 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  data = Object.assign( ELEMENT_DATA);
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.data);
  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  constructor(){
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  removeSelectedRows() {
    console.log(this.selection.selected)
     this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
      let index: number = this.data.findIndex(d => d === item);
      console.log(this.data.findIndex(d => d === item));
      this.dataSource.data.splice(index,1);

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
    });
    this.selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
    console.log(this.selection)
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
}
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: try this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.splice(index,1); / splice return a value, its not modify your actual object

Comment: anyway, is good to not make actions dirrectly on the dataSource, you can create a new obj and finally assign it to your dataSource.:
let source = this.dataSource.data;
let index = source.findIndex(d => d === item);
source = source.splice(index, 1);
this.dataSource.data = source;

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I will try..

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `mat-checkbox` instead? Do you want to restrict the user from deleting multiple rows at the same time? Why exactly are you using `mat-radio-button`?

Comment: @nash11 Yes.. I want to restrict the user from deleting multiple rows at the same time.. Only one row can be choose at one time

Comment: @AlleXyS..It not working

Comment: its no pint of using radiobuttons if you are deleting one at a time

Comment: If this is okey with you I can post an answer how to delete row by using id

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake Thanks for your suggestion but I need to using radio button because there are another module need me using radio button

Comment: but its not provide good user experience @swapy

Comment: yes I know but my lecturer tell me to do like that. @IndrajithEkanayake

Comment: @swapy answer updated as your requirement. If it helps dont forget to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're trying to use `selection.selected` which returns an array of all the rows that selected when in fact you want to only delete a single value from the table. If we want the user to be able to delete only a single row at a time, we only need to worry about the last row that was selected by the user. We can get rid of `$event.stopPropagation` so that whether the user clicks on the radio button or the row, the same event is triggered.

```html
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
    <mat-radio-button [checked]="selectedIndex === i">
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-cell>

...

<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selectedIndex = i">
</mat-row>
```

Then in your component

```js
selectedIndex: number;

removeSelectedRows() {
    let index: number = this.selectedIndex;
    this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data.slice(0, index), ...this.dataSource.data.slice(index + 1)];
    this.selectedIndex = null; // This will not be required when position is used to delete element
}
```

I've tried not to change too much in your code and do this using `slice` but IMO it would be better to use a unique value within `Element` like `position` and use `filter` to filter out the selected position from the `dataSource.data`.

```html
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-radio-button [checked]="selectedPosition === element.position">
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-cell>

...

<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selectedPosition = row.position">
</mat-row>
```

In the component

```js
selectedPosition: number;

removeSelectedRows() {
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(element => element.position !== this.selectedPosition);
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-forked).

Comment: could you edit my [https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-kttsot](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-kttsot)

Comment: when click radio button. I need to pass value when click button

Comment: @swapy - Sure, I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are deleting one row at a time it's no point of using radio buttons. I have done a few changes in your code and create output according to your requirement,

> Note: even though it is bad practice if you want to use radio buttons This is the answer

```
<mat-chip class="pointer" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="removeSelectedRows(element)">
        Remove Selected Rows
    </mat-chip>
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">


        <!-- Checkbox Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index; ">
                <mat-radio-button (click)="rowIndex(i)">
                </mat-radio-button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

in your component replace your delete function with following code,

```
index: number;
rowIndex(i){
this.index=i;
}

removeSelectedRows(element) {
      this.dataSource.data.splice(this.index,1);
      this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
  }
```

Hope this will help. Don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks

> [This is working Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-ndapmm)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... i feel so bad

Comment: what's the issue this is perfect to the point and easy to understand and this is working perfectly

Comment: @swapy edited my answer this is compliely working plese can you look again

Comment: could you give me link stackblitz that you make gif image?

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake - please don't pressurize the questioner to accept your answer. That is up to the questioner to decide. Instead justify how your answer is better than the others. While `_updateChangeSubscription` will work, it is doing a lot of other things under the hood which you don't need to do for just simply adding a row. So while your answer may seem easy to understand, remember you are calling a function which has code in it. So what you could easily do in 1 line of code is now 30 odd lines easily.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, this isn't out of spite. We're all here to learn. If you can justify how your answer is better, you can get my upvote as well :)

Comment: @swapy - This method is also rerendering your `paginator` and `sort` which is not required.